# Is there a way to list messages in gmail by descending order of size?

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

I'd like to get my gmail space down. Logically the way to do it would be to start with the largest messages first. ([Pareto chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_chart) reasoning - start with the things that give the largest benefit.)

My question is: **Is there a way to list messages in gmail by descending order of size?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible to have a list of email sorted by size with the Gmail web interface.

However, you can search by size:

[image]